# What is the height requirement for pilots in the Philippines?

Tags: medical, airline-pilot, student-pilot, philippines

I am not an airline pilot nor do I work in the industry but I'm looking forward to. I live in the Philippines, a part of South East Asia.

My question is: what is the current minimum height requirement in the Philippines to be a private airline or commercial airline pilot?

I was at a Aviation School seminar a few months ago and one of the guest asked the host if height still mattered and the host answered "not anymore because airplane pilot seats are now adjustable". That didn't really convince me because they might be biased considering they are looking for students.

Comment: I am roughly about `5'3"`.

Comment: welcome to aviation.SE. `The current requirement` is on topic, but `how you'd project the requirement will change in the future` is not (we don't do speculation here).
Are you interested in the requirement in the Philippines or somewhere else?

Comment: @Federico Thank you. I am interested in the requirement in the Philippines. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no minimum height stated in the [Philippines Civil Air Regulations](http://www.caap.gov.ph/index.php/downloads/finish/8-civil-aviation-regulation-car/192-002-part-2-personnel-licensing-8-2016) (section 2.10.2.2) for any class of medical (you need a class 1 medical for a commercial license). However, Philippine Airlines apparently [requires pilots](https://www.pilotcareercentre.com/Air-Carrier-PCC-Profile/476/Philippine%20Airlines) to be at least 5'4" / 162cm.

Comment: Thank you. Would you know the requirements from Cebu Pacific Airlines? That is a budget airlines in the Philippines.

Comment: @majidarif You're welcome! I have no idea about Cebu, unfortunately

Comment: [Cebu!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_uv8Ej4CEoQ) Sorry, my kids watched that incessantly, and it's still stuck in my head, 15 years later... :)

Comment: I just measured my height with a tape measure. It was 161.5cm. I'm 23. Can't even get the height requirement for PAL. :D